# How to automate uninstallation of software from old InstallShield?

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation

I'm writing a new installer for our legacy software. The installer was originally built with InstallShield Professional 6.40, and I'm now building it in Inno Setup. Because of major changes in the software's infrastructure, I need to first uninstall the old one so that I can perform a fresh installation using the new one (using Inno Setup).

The old version was installed in the drive's root (`C:\SoftwareName\`) And now I'm moving it to its appropriate place in the Program Files - as well as changing the registry key names. So although it's the same software, it's really treated as a completely different software.

I have found the entries in the registry for the old installation:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{[OUR GUID]}
```

And in here, there is an entry for uninstall information in `UninstallString`:

```
RunDll32 C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\engine\6\INTEL3~1\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{[OUR GUID]}\Setup.exe"
```

The second part of that, I know I can execute to launch the "Modify / Uninstall" wizard. But this needs to be automated, showing only the progress of uninstalling.

I've found the following links:

- http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/various-silent-parameters-uninstalling-installshield-applications
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.pcomm.doc%2Fbooks%2Fhtml%2Finstall_guide12.htm

But these appear to refer to newer versions of InstallShield. Our installation was with a very old one (6.40). I've managed to use that wisdom at least to initiate the uninstall like so...

```
RunDll32 C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\engine\6\INTEL3~1\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{[OUR GUID]}\Setup.exe" -10x9 -uninst -s -w
```

But it still gives a yes/no prompt if user wishes to uninstall...

[image: Uninstall Prompt]

This process is supposed to...

- Run silently with no wizard or user prompts
- Display just the progress of uninstall
- Wait until uninstall is complete before returning

But I have no luck accomplishing those things.

What's the appropriate way to perform this uninstall?

Comment: Try this link: http://www.itninja.com/question/silent-uninstall-of-a-setup-exe-created-in-installshield-6-0